# A formula that finds the value in range 1 in range 2 and returns the value in another column at that row position

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

| data1 | data2 | data2 | rusult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | apple | apple |
| c | b | banna | kiwi |
| b | c | kiwi | banna |
| c |  |  | kiwi |
| a |  |  | apple |
| a |  |  | apple |
| b |  |  | banna |
| c |  |  | kiwi |

[image]

Find the first value 'a' in data2.
Using the found row position as the index, find the value of the second column of data2.
Record in result.
Repeat process.
 I want to make this work as a formula!

Comment: look into VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(AF5:AF; AH:AI; 2; )))
```